# "GNOME Videos" (Totem) does not play web videos

Tags: codecs, video-player, totem, 16.10

When I copy a url from Youtube for example, and go to GNOME-Videos's menu and click on

> Movie>Add web video.

It does not work.

Just only once "GNOME Videos" showed me a error message saying that I have to install a codec, but I do not remember which.
I think it was html or h265,but I am not sure
[image of GNOME Videos (Totem).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcpx5.png)

Just in case when I installed the operating system I checked(ticked) the option

> "Install third-party software for graphics and Flash, mp3 and other media"

**what can we do for solve that matter?**
I realize that there exist an ubuntu restricted extras media codecs but as I have said above, I do not understand why I do not have them yet .

Comment: Additional codecs are provided by the packages *ubuntu-restricted-extras* or *ubuntu-restricted-addons*. However, it probably won't change the default behavior. It works on VLC though.

Comment: totem could only play youtube vids thru a plugin that no longer works & isn't available anymore  anyway. May still work in 14.04 to some limited extent. As mentioned vlc can work as does mpv

Comment: Just to note: checked, it's broken in 14.04 also